# Are complex twin js animations faster in two divs or two iframes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a complex javascript animation that is both GPU and CPU intensiive.  It was originally a single page, but I needed twin views, so to get a working model quick, I made a wrapper that loads it into two iframes.  This works really well.

The question is: Can I get better performance (especially on mobile) if I port it over to two div containers instead?

My understanding is that iframes are generally running on seperate threads, but I'm not sure if this applies only to sandboxed iframes (these are *not* sandboxed).  The scripts running in the two views are *almost*, but *not quite identical*.    Concievably I could refactor this but will take time, so I'd like to know if anyone has experience with something similar.

For the record, the two views are also overlaid and mixed with backgrounds, and each other using css blend-modes.  There is a lot going on with both js and css animations.

Anyway, the kids want me to play.  Hopefully I explained well, but I'll check back later to clear things up if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, as far as i know and experienced, each page it's a single thread, regardless for iframes.

The HTML5 standard implementation of multithread is trough [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) that's pritty well supported in its basic features by all modern browser and IE >= 10

Comment: Thanks, @holden.  Probably will be using a Web Worker anyway at some point, since it's a web-app for both Add to Home install and Android web-view embed.  I would like to refactor without iframes, but it's going to be a big task.   I have considered  loading the content into a pair of inline SVG's as foreignObject's, for easy export into png or jpg snapshots or video streams, but maybe stricter on the markup.  Experimented a bit.  It works, but not sure about quality or speed there.  Main thing is I need them to remain synchronized, and fast.  It's a real-time, multi-user app.